# Change of largest eigenvalue by change of single element of nonnegative square matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

I have matrices like A and B.
Rows $2-(n-1)$ are stochastic, row $n$ is sub stochastic and the first row differs always in the first entry.

I am interested in the largest eigenvalue ($\lambda_1$) of these matrices.

In case the first entry is $\frac{1}{2}$ (matrix A): $\lambda_1(A) = \cos (\frac{\pi}{2n+1})$.

For matrix B, $\lambda_1(B) = 1$.

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2}&  \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

$B = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2-\frac{2}{n}}&  \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Can I use this knowledge to get a good estimate on the eigenvalue of a matrix C in which the first entry is between $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{1}{2-\frac{2}{n}}$?

$C = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{2-\frac{2}{n^2}}&  \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & \dots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 &0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: The proof I've seen of the claim about matrix $A$ is via the discrete fourier transform; have you tried working through the steps of such a proof for matrix $C$? Or do you really want to know whether knowing something about matrices $A$ and $B$, you can discover something about a matrix $C$ that happens to look at lot like those first two? If you just want the top eigenvalue of $C$, it may be that knowing about $A$ and $B$ is a rathole rather than a useful way of getting to the thing you want.

Comment: I am interested in the top eigenvalue of $C$. And since the eigenvalues change continuously between $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2n+1})$ and $1$ I thought there might be a relation.; can you link me to literature proving the claim about matrix A?